# How can draw a ggplot with semi data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The question is so simple: I have 4 days with sales quantity. I would like to plot my data with ggplot as 20 days which means that my line should represent first 4 days, until 20 empty. 
The next step is gathering daily sales quantity from user which will update the sales data and line of plot either. (if you help me this stage -how to add row in data.frame via shiny, i will be so glad.)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707097/another-follow-up-to-add-values-to-a-reactive-table-in-shiny-when-we-already-h

or

[How to add a new row to uploaded datatable in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403004/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-uploaded-datatable-in-shiny)

And I have an Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class matrix.

Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class matrix.

```
 a <- rep(0, 20)
 b <- 1:20
 sales <- c(160, 150, 121, 93)
 dayid<- 1:4

 if(length(sales)<-20){rbind(sales, a[length(sales):length(a)])}
 if(length(dayid)<-20){rbind(dayid, b[length(dayid):length(b)])}
 xx <- cbind(dayid,sales)
  y<-ggplot(as.data.frame(xx), aes(dayid)) +  geom_line(size=1,aes(y=cumsum(sales), colour = "sales"))
```

Comment: it is not full data when we compare with 20 days. For example, I am in 4th day and there are 4 sales quantity of past 4 days which i can observe the pattern with ggplot. However, i would like to see empty 16 days, because i will play with this plot in shiny.

Answer (score 4):

Convert your matrix to data.frame

```
y<-ggplot(as.data.frame(xx), aes(dayid)) + 
          geom_line(size=1,aes(y=cumsum(sales), colour = "sales"))
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing. But this time i have warning about Warning message:
Removed 16 rows containing missing values (geom_path).  It shows just 4 days 4 sales. How can i force to plot as 20 days?

Comment: To simulate your code, we need the value of Col2 wich was not provided. Check the value of your matrix "dayid" to see if there was no NA's in the data before you plot it.

Comment: This is my mistake that Col2 should be written as sales. I edited!

Comment: The problem is with the rbind between sales and a in the first if, and that is causing NA's, because sales has 4 columns and a has 20. Take a look at sales after you make the rbind. Hope it helps.